# Typescript Union: Property 'value' does not exist on type '""'

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have an interface with union types, and when I am trying to access the value it gives me error.

This is my interface:

```
interface DataItemI{
  sys_id:string;
  name:string;
  parent:string|{value:string}
}
```

and data set as:

```
const dataList:DataItemI[]=[
    {
        sys_id:'c1',
        name:'p1-c1',
        parent:{  value:'p1'}
    },
    {
        sys_id:'p1',
        name:'p1',
        parent:''
    },
    {
        sys_id:'c2',
        name:'p1-c1',
        parent:{  value:'p1'}
    },
    {
        sys_id:'sc1',
        name:'p1-c1-sc1',
        parent:{  value:'c1'}
    },
    {
        sys_id:'p2',
        name:'p2',
        parent:''
    },
    {
        sys_id:'p2c1',
        name:'p2-c1',
        parent:{  value:'p2'}
    },
];
```

and now I cam trying to loop over the array and get the parent value if present else default value as `root`

```
dataList.forEach(dataItem=>{
key=dataItem?.parent?.value || 'root';
  console.log(key); 
});
```

But I am getting the error:

```
 Property 'value' does not exist on type '"" | { value: string; }'.
      Property 'value' does not exist on type '""'.
    
    58   key=dataItem?.parent?.value || 'root';
                               ~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `parent` can be `string` or `{ value: string }` and `string` doesn't have property `value`. You'll need to refine `parent`'s type first (using type guard), then you'll be able to access `value` property:

```
const parent = dataItem.parent;
const key = (typeof parent === 'string' ? parent : parent.value) || 'root';
```

`typeof parent === 'string'` is a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAkpAtl5AbwChlkBnAT3IH1gATALgrClAHMBuU5EOXCM3KsO3MgAc4UCOCEiQ7ZAB8iyAG5wANgFdBLNguQBfYieIIA9iGHJ6GOABlgw5ukw4I+ANoBdZAF5kLx4SMjIqWgZmAHIEAEZogBoeMj4BGPE4gFp4pJTkSWlZVQ0dPWjM6OMeI2SyULCIuiZkCoS6sLTyyo6JKRkwGOiajobw6maYhAAmPLDefm7s3N6C-uLCdS1dDITqslqQ-Kao1vIV-K7dnOzz9vzCgeZN0p3W3P3jUeOJ04rZ1ZXVriAEPdaDVrDA7feYnFr-C7zIH-G5zMKPDZbMoZWafQ4+bjEOyYJzCAB0MAsUAAoogABYACmJ2DwAQAfEQeJZrGA1kVeYFmR5cGSMWAxMhuTYANYQSgBZAMsCUcQQCwwPkDAL+QLRYQGdhVAD8mvAyGYYrJrwgAEplCpolALBYwNEJVKLJoIGTNBZ2AzZZQbdwjMGgA)

Comment: Which version of typescript do you use? As you can see works fine with the latest one. Could you setup reproducible example on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play ?